# PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What might be the error?
I looked at similar problems, downgrading the version to 2.0 is workaround but this is not true

DAL.dll

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

UIWEBAPP.dll

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CKEditor" Version="3.6.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey mate try these steps because this way works !!!

1.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0
```

2.

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0" />
```

3.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=serveraddresst;Database=db_name;User=db_username;Password=db_password" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -c DataBaseContext -o Models
```